# Rename Article SLUG if already exists

Tags: php, sql, rename, slug

On my Articles Site I have ID & Article SLUG setup but I use slug instead of ID. Slug is set as primary unique !

but when user add existing slug again results in die with mysql error 
Duplicate entry for key 'PRIMARY'

I changed the code to check before insert

```
    $qry="select * from marticles where slug='$slg'";
$res=mysql_query($qry) or die("Error in query!");
$count = mysql_num_rows($res);
if($count > 0) {
    echo "Slug Already Exists! Pls change Title/Slug";
    }
```

It now shows Error Message to User Before Insert

But I want to auto rename slug instead of error message 
e.g. If Previous Slug is "article-on-environment"
If user insert same slug again then it will change to "article-on-environment-2"
& then next ""article-on-environment-3" so on

I need help in search of same old slug and rename.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do the insert and then on mysql_error check the error code and if it is the duplicate key code, change the slug.

```
$slug='test';
$orig=$slug;
while(!$done) {
    $i++;
    mysql_query("insert into table set slug = '$slug'");
    if(mysql_errno() == 1062) {
        $slug=$orig."-$i";
    } else {
        $done=true;
    }
}
```